# arrange data retrieved from DB in table

Tags: php

Im using the following code to view pictures inside a table(get its info from DB)  I want to view 3-pic in each row , the problem occur when the number of pictures is not a Complications of three,like:4,5,7,8 .. and so on,the first column will not contain three pic either 1 or 2 ,I want this case to be in the last row not in first row.
problem shape:

```
* *
* * *
* * *
```

I want it like :

```
* * *
* * *
* *
```

here the code :

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","flip2");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM images";
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM threads";

    $result=$mysqli->query($query) or die('Error, query failed'.mysql_error());
    $result2=$mysqli->query($query2) or die('Error, query     failed'.mysql_error());


    $i = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
        if($i%3==0){
            echo "<tr>";
        }

        $z=$row['threads_id'];
        $t=$mysqli->query("SELECT Title FROM threads WHERE threads.id=$z order by threads.id DESC ") or die('Error, query failed'.mysql_error());
        $t1=mysqli_fetch_array($t);
        $title=$t1['Title'];


        echo "<td>"."<figure class='cap-bot' id='fig'>".'<img src="'.$row['path'].'" id="c_img">'.
            "<figcaption id='fig_cap'>"."$title"."<br>"."<span>"."&nbsp click on : &nbsp &nbsp".
            "</span>"."<a onClick='choice($row[threads_id])'  href='c_info.php?id=$row[threads_id]' id='l1'>"."more details"."</a>"."</figcaption>"."<td>"."</figure>".
            "<form action='c_info.php' method='post'><input type='hidden' id='$z' name='kk' value='$z'></form>";

        $i--;
        if($i%3==0){
            echo "<tr>";
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: welcome @yousef, for your next answer/question, I recommend you to have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<tr>` with `</tr>` at the end of a loop. And start counting `$i` from **zero**.

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
    if ($i%3==0){
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    // your code here

    if ($i%3==0){
        echo "</tr>"; // TR should be closed, not another one opened 
    }
    $i++;
}
```